# Using Jquery "this" variable to toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this Onclick function.

```
$('.tc-navigation > li').on("click", function(e) {
$(this).toggleClass('subb');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('subb'); 
return false; // keep the event from bubbling 
});
```

When a link .tc-navigation > li is clicked, i want to add a class to a further nested ul inside the li element like this:-

```
 $(this) > ul.toggleClass('subb');
```

but its currently not working. I am a bit new to Jquery if anybody can assist me.

Comment: You're trying to use CSS syntax in javascript.  Try `$(this).find('ul').toggleClass('subb')`;

Comment: `$(this).find('> ul').toggleClass('subb');` doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielBeck your code may work, but as he wants to update the child `ul`(s) using `>` is necessary .

Comment: @MehdiDehghani All the question says is "nested", so we have no way of   knowing whether the selection needs to be limited to direct children (if so I would use `children()` rather than `find()`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) if you only want immediate child of that `<li>`

```
$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('subb');
```